# REST Server broke when changing servers - Drupal 6.22

Tags: web-services, rest, drupal-6

**The Problem**

- Drupal 6.22 install with REST server and Services modules.
- I do a POST to `http://domainname.co.uk/rest/users/logout` and I get a 500 error.
- In the Logs:

  ```
  PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function services_resource_uri_formatter() in /home/organicd/public_html/domainname.co.uk/live/public/sites/all/modules/rest_server/includes/RESTServer.inc on line 15
  ```

**Background**

I had the Drupal install with REST server installed and working perfectly. The whole install was moved to a different server (not by me). I was told that all folders have been kept intact. The only difference was that the old server had an SSL certificate.

With the old server, I could do a POST using REST Console to https://domainname.co.uk/rest/users/logout and it would logout the current user. Now I get a 500 error with the log entry above.

**What I've Tried**

- **Disabling REST Server.** I read that Services 3.0 has REST built into it. When I disable REST Server and Services, then re-enable Services, I get:

  ```
   The plugin definition of services_ctools_export_ui cannot locate schema services_endpoint.
  ```

  and I don't see anywhere in administer by module that I can setup the REST settings.
- **Different version of Services**. Tried updating from `6.x-3.0-rc1` to `6.x-3.0` but it doesn't make any difference
- **Hacking the code**. I found a version of the services.module that has the `services_resource_uri_formatter()` function. I added that in, but got a similar error saying it couldn't find another function. I sense this road leads to madness.

**Versions**

- Drupal 6.22
- Ctools 6.x-1.x-dev
- REST Server 6.x-2.0-beta3
- Services 6.x-3.0-rc1 (also tried latest version of 6.x-3.0)

**Question**

How do I get Drupal 6.22 REST to work once again? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I have the very same problem here. Did you find the solution?

Comment: Yep, I did. Sorry - should have posted the answer. Posting now...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks John and Mir,

We realized that what happened in our case was a conflict between the rest_server single module and the rest server capability that is included on the services module itself.

We had our module dependent on the rest_server module and we were enabling and loading it. This module was broken regarding services.

The solution for our case was to disable the single rest_server and delete it. Disable services and enable again. there should appear another rest_server version 3 which is the one that comes with services.

Then we enable this rest server module and it all works like magic.

Regards.

Comment: Ah yes - I think I made this mistake too, and it was this combined with the authentication that made it break... maybe. It was so long ago that I'm struggling to remember now. Thanks for giving a more recent and detailed answer than mine!

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the Services 3 make sure you don't put a dependency on Rest Server contrib module(Rest Server comes bundled with Services 3).

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that I'd not properly set up my REST service within the admin interface.

1. Log into the admin interface then go to Site Building > Services > List.
2. Click "Edit"
3. Scroll down to the bottom and tick the box alongside "Session Authentication" and click Save

I also needed to tick all "Response formatters" and "Request parsing" boxes under the Server tab of the service edit screen.

I hope this fixes the problem for others!